# How to fetch text in pre tag in python using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have seen various examples on stackoverflow.com but nothing solves my problem ,I have the following site: https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme.

This site has a pre tag and has text inside it but when I try to fetch the text inside the pre tag it only returns []

code:

```
requester = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req=Request("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme",headers=requester)
u =urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(u.read(), features="lxml")
text = soup.find('pre')

print(text)
```

output: `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL returns a `JSON` so `BeautifulSoup` won't do much here.

Try this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme").json()
print(r['title'], r['url'])
```

Output: `Pls send help https://i.redd.it/67scdl09rkn51.jpg`

And the entire response looks like this:

`{'postLink': 'https://redd.it/iu4q6f', 'subreddit': 'memes', 'title': 'Pls send help', 'url': 'https://i.redd.it/67scdl09rkn51.jpg', 'nsfw': False, 'spoiler': False, 'author': 'deinie', 'ups': 9787}`

Answer (score 0):

since your code returns output as `{"postLink":"https://redd.it/iu9v3o","subreddit":"me_irl","title":"me_irl","url":"https://i.redd.it/b4ccrc396mn51.jpg","nsfw":false,"spoiler":false,"author":"TheNBplant","ups":43}` there is no pre tag here. so the output is none.